# How do I fallback to the Default TaskScheduler from a custom TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Let's say I want to create a custom TaskScheduler, but inside it, fall back to the default if some criteria do not apply. How do I do that?

E.g.

```
protected override void QueueTask(Task task) {
   if (/* some condition */) {
       /* schedule task manually, does not matter */
   }

   /* queue task on default -- how? */
}

protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks() {
    return Enumerable.Concat(/* my tasks */, /* tasks from default -- how? */);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can (or should) do this, even if you resorted to reflection hacks. In theory, you'd need to derive your custom `TaskScheduler` from existing non-abstract task scheduler, e.g. [`ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs#ede3f49dfeb3b299).

However, you can't because [all non-abstract implementations](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=QueueTask) of `TaskScheduler` in TPL are either `private` or `internal`.

In case with `TaskScheduler.QueueTask`, it might be *tempting* to simply forward the call to [`Task.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321282%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
protected override void QueueTask(Task task) {
   if (/* some condition */) {
       /* schedule task manually, does not matter */
   }

   /* queue task on default -- how? */
   task.Start(TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

However, you can not do this, either. The [implementation of `Task.Start`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs#58f38b23f90258a4) calls `TaskScheduler.QueueTask` internally, which would result in infinite recursion.

Moreover, the `Task` object stores a reference to the task scheduler inside `Task.Start`. So, say, if you used reflection to call `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.QueueTask`, it would break the connection between the task and its task scheduler.

So, there's a good reason that `QueueTask`, `GetScheduledTasks` and some other methods of `TaskScheduler` are declared as `protected`. If you're into implementing a custom task scheduler, you have to provide the full implementation.

Comment: I see why you are saying why I can't do this, but why do you think I should no do this?

Comment: @AndreyShchekin, for this reason: *the `Task` object stores a reference to the task scheduler inside `Task.Start`*. If you start the task with your custom task scheduler (via `Task.Start` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`), a reference to *your* task scheduler will be stored. Then inside your `QueueTask` you'd call `defaultTaskScheduler.QueueTask`, and the task would run on a different task scheduler from what it kept the reference to. The results of this might be unpredictable.

Comment: I would argue it is no different from any normal decorator -- for the outside world the task is actually running on my scheduler, it is just that its internal implementation uses another scheduler to help with that.

On the other hand ThreadPoolScheduler, I believe, throws when passed the task from another scheduler. 

Anyway this whole API seems to be very badly designed with regards to extensibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- I do agree there is no good solution to this problem.